# Windows Vista to Windows 7 Gbit LAN slow file copy

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking, windows-7

I have two computers with gigabit LAN, one running Windows 7 and the other running Vista.

I have a D-Link DIR-655 router, with gigabit LAN ports.

I created a shared directory on the Vista computer, mapped it as a network drive on the Win 7 computer, and tried copying a 2 GB file... and it's going at 900 KB/s

Yep... 900 kilobytes per second, about 7 Mb/s.

Why so slow? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check your hard drive first. copy between harddrive/directory. it should be way above 10MB/s. if this fails on either machine, the hard drive is to blame.

2) then check your network cable. 900KB/sec is near the theoretical speed of 10Mbps lan. that sort of lan cable should not be possible to be bought these days. check if there are 8 lines in the cable. change cable and test again if necessary. the network connection should show a "1 Gbps" speed on the dialog in this case.

3) sometimes reverting the router to the default settings fix a problem or two. sometimes routers needs to be restarted.

try these three first.

Comment: It wound up being that the network adaptor on the Vista machine was somehow set to 10 Mbps instead of 1 Gbps or Auto. No idea how that happened, as I never manually changed that.

Answer (score 0):

> Why so slow? Any ideas?

Are the network cables undamaged? Have you tested them? Are they Cat5e cables? Are the network adapters on the PCs gigabit?

It's probably Vista at fault. See [this](http://www.ads-links.com/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-vista-slow-network-transfer.html).